# Labelling a matrix using a brace in latex

Tags: matrices, labels

[image]

Hey, I want to add two braces as labels for a matrix. I am able to add the top brace label "r". But when I add the bottom "m - r" label, it becomes branched. Here's my code in Latex.

```
\[R = 
\raisebox{0.5em}{$r \left\{ \rule[2em]{0pt}{0pt} \right. $} 
\raisebox{-2em}{$m - r \left\{ \rule[0.5em]{0pt}{0pt} \right. $}
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|cccc}
  1 & & & b_{1, r + 1} & b_{1, r + 2} & \ldots & b_{1n}\\
  & \ddots & & \ldots & \ldots & \ddots & \ldots \\
  & & 1 & b_{r, r + 1} & b_{r, r + 2} & \ldots & b_{rn} \\
  \hline
  & O & & & O & & 
\end{array}
\right]
\]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Hope `nicematrix` may complete your expectation

Comment: I know the site is about TeX questions, but IMHO this would be a great opportunity to ask yourself what you really want/need to say.  The display without the braces makes it pretty clear that there are n columns and the "identity bit" is r x r.  So you could omit braces and write the passage as "...the m x n matrix <display>R=...</display>.  If you feel this is not clear enough, add, "where the first r rows begin with an r x r identity matrix and the remaining m-r rows are entirely zero".  It's not *obligatory* to write everything in symbols.

Comment: BTW re my previous comment: I tried to write things like $m\times n$ but it did not render properly.  Is mathmode not recognised in comments on this site?  Or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution with `nicematrix`. Note the use of `\cdots` and `\vdots`. Also the `O` in the bottom right quadrant is centered in the block, not in its own column.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\[R = 
\begin{bNiceArray}{ccc|cccc}[first-col, margin]
\Block{3-1}{\scriptstyle {r\hspace{2mm}}} & 1 & & & b_{1, r + 1} & b_{1, r + 2} & \cdots & b_{1n}\\
 & & \ddots & & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
 & & & 1 & b_{r, r + 1} & b_{r, r + 2} & \cdots & b_{rn} \\ \hline
\scriptstyle {m-r\hspace{2mm}} & & O & & \Block{1-4}{O} & & & 
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix\{{1-1}{3-7}.[left-xshift=3mm]
  \SubMatrix\{{4-1}{4-7}.[left-xshift=3mm]
\end{bNiceArray}.
\]
\end{document}
```

As an alternative, you can use the `tikz` libraries `decorations.pathreplacing` and `calligraphy` together with `nicematrix` to draw the braces. This has the advantage of giving the braces the same thickness regardless of their length, but `nicematrix` ignores the braces and their labels when creating space for the matrix, so additional space must be placed manually. I used `\hspace{7mm}` in the code below.

Also (optional), `shorten <=` does not work with the calligraphic brace, so the endpoints should use `yshift` to shorten the braces.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, calligraphy}
\tikzset{mybrace/.style={thick, decorate, decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=2pt, raise=2mm}}}

\begin{document}
\[R = \hspace{7mm}
\begin{bNiceArray}{ccc|cccc}[margin]
1 & & & b_{1, r + 1} & b_{1, r + 2} & \cdots & b_{1n}\\
  & \ddots & & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  & & 1 & b_{r, r + 1} & b_{r, r + 2} & \cdots & b_{rn} \\ \hline
  & O & & \Block{1-4}{O} & & & 
\CodeAfter
  \tikz{
    \draw[mybrace]([yshift=1pt]4-|1)--node[left=2mm]{$\scriptstyle r$}([yshift=-1pt]1-|1);
    \draw[mybrace]([yshift=1pt]5-|1)--node[left=2mm]{$\scriptstyle m-r$}([yshift=-1pt]4-|1);
  }
\end{bNiceArray}.
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! It is a perfect replica of the expected output. I guess I have a lot to explore in the nice matrix package.

Comment: Could it be possible to have "same looking" for the braces?

Comment: @JustAnAveragePerson `nicematrix` is a great package.

Comment: @projetmbc: The only way I can think of is to use the `calligraphic brace` decoration from the Ti*k*Z `calligraphy` library.

Comment: Good point. I will play with it.

Comment: @projetmbc: I added a solution with `calligraphic brace`.

Comment: Better output! Great.